# Добавить значения в бд по нажатию кнопки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в которой выводятся данные из mysql.
В самой таблице есть 3 поля, в которые можно добавить значения и кнопка.
Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки в базу добавлялись значения с этих 3 полей и одно булево значение.

Вот так выглядит таблица:

```
<?php
            $post = get_users();
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($post as $users): ?>
            <div class="main-content-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- table primary start -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 mt-5">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 class="header-title">Анкета №<?=$users['id']?> (<?=$users['order_date']?> <?=$users['order_time']?>)</h4>
                              <h6>Позвонить Менеджеру: <?=$users['surname']?> <?=$users['name']?> <?=$users['second_name']?> <?=$users['phone']?></h6>
                              <div class="single-table">
                                  <div class="table-responsive">
                                      <table class="table text-center">
                                          <thead class="text-uppercase bg-primary">
                                              <tr class="text-white">
                                                  <th scope="col">Номер</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">ФИО</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Дата рождения</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Место рождения</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Гражданство</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Срок</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Доставка</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">На доставку</th>
                                              </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                          <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                  <th scope="row"><?=$users['phone']?></th>
                                                  <td><?=$users['surname']?> <?=$users['name']?> <?=$users['second_name']?></td>
                                                  <td><?=$users['birth_date']?></td>
                                                  <td><?=$users['birth_place']?></td>
                                                  <td><?=$users['citizenship']?></td>
                                                  <td><?=$users['term']?></td>
                                                  <td><div class="form-group">
                                                      <select name="delivery_adress" class="form-control">
                                                          <option>Авиамоторная</option>
                                                          <option>Автозаводская</option>
                                                                                      <option>Электрозаводская</option>
                                                          <option>Юго-Западная</option>
                                                          <option>Южная</option>
                                                          <option>Ясенево</option>


                                                      </select>
                                                  </div></td>
                                                <td><button type="button" formmethod="post" name="delivery" action="/del.php" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success mb-3">Отправить</button></td>

                                              </tr>
                                          </tbody>

                                          <thead class="text-uppercase bg-primary">
                                              <tr class="text-white">
                                                  <th scope="col">Документ</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Номер документа</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Дата выдачи</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Кем выдан</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Комментарий</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Дата доставки</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Время доставки</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Отказ</th>
                                              </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                          <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                  <th scope="row"><?=$users['doc']?></th>
                                                  <td><?=$users['doc_id']?></td>
                                                  <td><?=$users['doc_date']?></td>
                                                  <td><?=$users['doc_publish']?></td>
                                                  <td><?=$users['comment']?></td>
                                                  <td><div class="form-group">
                                                          <input class="form-control" type="date" name="delivery_date" value="2018-03-05" id="example-date-input">
                                                      </div></td>

                                                  <td><div class="form-group">
                                                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="delivery_date" value="С 10 до 12" id="example-text-input">
                                                  </div></td>
                                                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger mb-3" action="<? $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Users (reject) VALUES (1)";
                                                      $result = mysqli_query($sql1);?>">Отказ</button></td>
                                              </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- table primary end -->


                </div>

            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

А вот файл del.php, в который сделан Post-запрос.

```
<?php
//Параметры подключения в БД
$host = "localhost"; //имя хоста
$database = "test1"; //имя базы
$user = "root"; //пользователь
$password = ""; //пароль
$dbtable = "Users"; //таблица

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));


if(isset($_POST['delivery']))
{
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO $dbtable (delivery, delivery_adress, delivery_date, delivery_time) VALUES ('1', 'delivery_adress', 'delivery_date', 'delivery_time')";
    $result = mysqli_query($SQL);
}
?>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы значения из полей ввода delivery_adress, delivery_date, delivery_time добавлялись в соответствующую таблицу, а  delivery присваивалось значение "1".
Таблица уже заполнена, а эти значения пустые. Возможно, я неправильно SQL-запрос составил и некорректно передаю значения. 
Объясните, пожалуйста, что я неправильно делаю.

Comment: вам нужно использовать `ajax`, чтобы передать данные на сервер и там их обработать (в данном случае добавить)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а можете подробно объяснить, как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Раз таблица уже заполнена,  т.е. запись в БД существует (если я правильно понял), то вам нужен не insert, а update. обязательно надо передать id записи, которую обновлять. обычно его держат в форме в input hidden и передают на сервер с остальными данными. Что касается передачи значений из полей в запрос (в данный момент у вас в запросе просто текст, константа), то посмотрите примеры тут http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php Сами пришедшие с клиента значения доступны в переменных $_POST

Comment: [вот](http://dnzl.ru/view_post.php?id=271) пример, как работает ajax + php. Он нужен чтобы асинхронно (на самом деле можно и  синхронно, но зачем) дать запрос на сервер и получить от него ответ

Comment: @Mike да, всё верно, таблица уже существует и заполнена, кроме этих полей. Попробую через update.
Может подскажете как правильно передать id заодно?

Comment: @Mike можете посмотреть, в правильном ли я направлении понял?
добавил в код 
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?=$users['id']?>"> 
тут я получаю id.

затем в del.php делаю запрос
$SQL = "UPDATE $dbtable SET delivery='1', delivery_adress='delivery_adress', delivery_time='delivery_time', delivery_date='delivery_date' WHERE id='form_id'";

Comment: в общем правильное. но сейчас вы ищете запись с id текстом 'form_id' и в поля соответственно заносите просто текст. вам надо заменить все эти константы на знаки `?` (не заключая их в кавычки) и использовать bind_param что бы привязать `$_POST['delivery_adress']` и т.п. переменные при привязке перечисляются в том же порядке что и `?` в тексте запроса